# Create Facebook page event without it turning up on Fans' feeds?

Tags: facebook

I am administering a Facebook page.

I just created the first event for the page. Now the problem is, the event turned up on my personal feed. I have to assume that it turns up in the feed of every one of the 300+ fans the page has.

This is undesired, as I would like to add a whole bunch of events without annoying the  fans.

Can I "secretly" add events to a Facebook page without the page's fans getting notified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure but at least back in the old days that would do the trick:

Create an event and right afterwards delete the notification that appeared on the wall of your page.

Comment: It's *that* easy! I didn't realize that an announcement is generated on the page's wall, and that this can be removed. Thanks!

Comment: @Pekka and it works for any action that you want to hide from your _folowers_ in general on Facebook :)

Comment: yup, I just realized this applies to everything. Problem solved! :)